# Foreign Key dependencies While deleting table

Tags: django, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, rdbms

In my Postgresql, I have a main table **TABLE_MAIN** containing 10 columns in which 7 of the columns are foreign keys to the primary keys of the other 7 tables.

Now, in one of the tables (**not TABLE_MAIN**) let's call it **child_table**, whenever I click **Refresh** Button in the UI, I am emptying all the data in **child_table** using the following Django ORM query and then insert relevant data.

```
child_table.objects.all().delete()
```

I have lots of important data in **TABLE_MAIN** of around 1000 rows, and to my shock, whenever I click the Refresh button in the UI(which deleted all the data in **child_table**) I found that **TABLE_MAIN** data is completely gone.

What is happening here? Is it due to the foreign key dependencies??

and the other child_tables data is completely safe, but TABLE_MAIN data is lost.

**Deleting one primary key** in **child_table** for which it's a foreign key from **TABLE_MAIN** field will affect to lose all the data in TABLE_MAIN?

Comment: How are your models written? Can you show us a part of your code showing those foreign keys declarations?

Comment: It almost sounds like your foreign key constraints are backwards.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte , all foreign keys are in the following format "models.ForeignKey(table, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)"

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' , What do you mean by backward?... I said one of the column in TABLE_MAIN is a foreign key to the child_table(by default it maps to primary of this child table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's ForeignKey field provides a special option [on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) that let's you instruct Django what to do in case of related models deletion. You probably have this value set to **CASCADE** which deletes all objects containing ForeignKey whenever you delete some object from db. If you don't want this behavior, you should consider passing on of *PROTECT*, *SET_NULL*, *SET_DEFAULT* to on_delete option in your ForeignKey fields.

Comment: "models.ForeignKey(TABLE_MAIN, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)"  is the attribute i have currently in my model.... do you want me to remove on_delete=models.CASCADE?

Comment: on_delete is required by Django, so you should change it to one of the options that i mentioned above, e.g on_delete=models.PROTECT

Comment: I am okay with deleting all the data in the child_table and inserting, but I want it not affect other tables, so as you mentioned above, I will be using "on_delete=models.SET_NULL" and null=True .....Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Yeap, that will work. However, note that your field must allow null values in this case,  e.g. ForeignKey(some_model, null=True)

Comment: sure, Thanks a lot!  I am glad that I figured this out in much early state